# What would the best practice be for installing any OS onto an external drive that could boot and run or install for use on a Lenovo Thinkcentre m82?

Tags: usb, operating-systems, bootable-media, external-drive, rebuild

I first got the desktop from the scrap bin at my old job, it had no ram or internal hard drive. Just got the ram sticks in mail and now it goes to the recovery menu. I have a win 10 and a win8.1 installation media downloaded also a kalilinux iso. I have 3 external drives to choose from. one Crucial X6 SSD 500GB, Then I have 2 HDD - one HP Pocket Drive 500GB , and a buffalo 1TB - both with USB 3.0. (SSD uses USB-C)

What are my options and how do I need to proceed/beware of? I'm low on funds so I'm avoiding the thought of buying an internal sata drive, but would consider getting an adapter if it's needed to install windows. Also I downloaded Win 8.1 because the computer had a license for 8.1 pro or enterprise which I have been wanting to use. But I'm also a little curious if it would be noticable to my old employers IT dept if the license was in use again suddenly. (Or to microsoft for that matter)  If it's easiest to install some portable linux distro I'm totally down, I'm just excited to have this side project that I got for free.

Main actual question : Do I need to partition whichever disk a certain way for best practice? And also, would I need to put the installation media executable on the disk and plug into the m82 (target machine) to install? or could I install the OS to the disk using my laptop and then just plug n play?

Thanks very much - Tommy

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: With just a screwdriver, all your external drives can also become internal drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just shuck the SSD from its case & mount it internally. Windows doesn't like being installed on external media.

Then I'd install Win 8.1. You won't find out until you've installed it whether the license will carry over. If it previously had Pro it will, Enterprise wouldn't be able to find its licensing server to validate.

If 8.1 was licensed, then you'll be able to upgrade to Win 10 with no further issues, otherwise you're going to have to buy it.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of that, once out of the case how would I connect it to the sata port?  And as far as the installation goes do I need to worry about making the system reserve and boot partitions? and would I run the setup and install to the disk first? or move the executable to the disk, mount it to the desktop and then install from there?

Comment: Inside the case, the drive should just be a regular SATA drive; you can get cables from any computer shop. If you made your USB sticks with the Media Creation Tool, they'll walk you through the setup process.

Comment: So far I've been able to the external drive via usb installing windows to go with AOMEI onto the Crucial X6. Little bit slow which I'm guessing might be from the USB port but I wasn't sure if this kind of eSSD used some weird kind of adapter, but I'll probably try taking it out and doing it internally like you said just to see the difference. 8.1 loaded up and was able to get the product key from regedit no problem! Thanks very much ya'll were a big help!